# Error loading 'libsolclient.dll'

Tags: c#, dll, solace

I'm at a bit of a loss. I am trying to get I am getting this error:

InnerException = {"Unable to load DLL 'libsolclient.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}

When trying to execute:

`ContextFactoryProperties contextFactoryProperties = new ContextFactoryProperties { SolClientLogLevel = SolLogLevel.Warning };
  ContextFactory.Instance.Init(cfp);`

I have am referencing: SolaceSystems.Solclient.Messaging.10.0.0\build..\lib\net20\x64\SolaceSystems.Solclient.Messaging.dll

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you building your project in AnyCPU, x86 or x64?

Comment: Have tried all three. What's weird though is that it's very intermittent. It work's sometimes and other times it doesn't...

Comment: Is there a reason to use the .net 2.0 version of this assembly? Maybe a newer version would work better (if available). Otherwise you can try the usual Restart Visual Studio > Clean Solution > Rebuild...

Comment: no newer version. Tried the clean / rebuild as well.

Comment: How are you referencing the DLLs, and which version of Visual Studio is this? Also, whenever you encounter the error, can you verify whether the dll is present?

Comment: Using the newest (at least by this date) [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SolaceSystems.Solclient.Messaging) should solve the problem, since `libsolclient.dll` should be imported by `.targets` file from the package.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is not need to add the libsolclient.dll as a reference, just add it to the project as "new Item" and change the properties of it to copy it to the output directory (copy if newer is enough).